# In each row in a 2D array, match on a value, to produce a list of column positions where the match occurred

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In each row in an (N rows x M columns) array, match on a scalar value, to produce a (N rows x 1 column) list of column positions where the match occurred (i.e. between 1 and M)

I need to find the first occurrence of 0 in each row, and generate a list, e.g.

```
2   0
4   0
6   0
8   0
10  0
0   0
```

it should produce

```
2
2
2
2
2
1
```

and for:

```
250 250 0
500 0   0
750 250 0
0   0   0
```

it should produce

```
3
2
3
1
```

As I need to wrap this into a `LAMBDA` I cannot use `ROW()` as it refers to a position in the current sheet, and I also cannot use helper columns / rows.

This is one small piece, where I'm stuck, of a larger problem. Context is provided if you think this is an X-Y problem and there's a better way to solve the larger problem. Having said that, being able to solve this specific piece (where I'm using `MATCH`) would be useful as it is probably generalisable to `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM` etc.

---

## Context

What I'm trying to do is, on demand, in a single formula, generate a sequence like, based on a "step" of `2`, and options of `{12,2}` and a max of `12`.

```
2
2
2
2
2
12
```

It needs to be generalisable to other inputs, e.g. options of `{1000,500,250}`, max is `1000`, step is `250`:

```
250
500
250
1000
```

A side note: each of the options is exactly divisible into the smaller options, i.e. 250 is divisible by 250, 500 is divisible by 500 and 250, 1000 is divisible by 1000 and 500 and 250, and the intention is to grab the largest value in that set.

(I'll be able to easily wrap this into a `LAMBDA`)

## Exploration

Now I can easily generate an array like, using `SEQUENCE(1000/250,,250,250)`.

```
250
500
750
1000
```

or with `SEQUENCE(12/2,,2,2)`

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
```

And I know that `MOD(this, option) == 0`

```
with
SWITCH(0,
  MOD(this,12),12,
  MOD(this,2),2
)
2 => 2
4 => 2
6 => 2
8 => 2
10 => 2
12 => 12
```

or

```
with
SWITCH(0,
  MOD(this,1000),1000,
  MOD(this,500),500,
  MOD(this,250),250,
)
250 => 250
500 => 500
750 => 250
1000 => 1000
```

## Idea

My idea is to generate a dynamic 2 dimensional array, where there's a row for each generated number, and a column for each of the options, and mod them, for example, with `MOD(SEQUENCE(12/2,,2,2),{12,2})`:

```
2   0
4   0
6   0
8   0
10  0
0   0
```

or with `MOD(SEQUENCE(1000/250,,250,250),{1000,500,250})`

```
250 250 0
500 0   0
750 250 0
0   0   0
```

**The second-last step I would have to do is get the position of the first column that's `0` for each row, and use `INDEX(options, position)` to get the actual option.**

The last step would be to take these positions and look into the original options with `INDEX({12,2},{2,2,2,2,2,1})` or with `INDEX({1000,500,250},{3,2,3,1})` (technically these are horizontal, but I can `TRANSPOSE`)

## Stuck

I'm stuck on the second-last step. How do I get the column position of the first 0 value in each row?

I'm trying to use `MATCH` but it does not do what I want; it seems to produce a single value only.

The formula for the second-last step should result in a 6x1 array, so that I can use it in the last step:

```
2 // position 2 of {12,2} == 2
2 // position 2 of {12,2} == 2
2 // position 2 of {12,2} == 2
2 // position 2 of {12,2} == 2
2 // position 2 of {12,2} == 2
1 // position 1 of {12,2} == 12
```

or

```
3 // position 3 of {1000,500,250} == 250
2 // position 2 of {1000,500,250} == 500
3 // position 3 of {1000,500,250} == 250
1 // position 1 of {1000,500,250} == 1000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
=BYROW(A1:C4,LAMBDA(x,XMATCH(0,x)))
```

[image]

seems to return your desired results

Or even:

```
=BYROW(1:6,LAMBDA(x,XMATCH(0,x)))
```

[image]